# Using Javascript find array values in another array and in order

Tags: javascript, arrays

Here is one to get your brain going! I've not had any luck with it.

```
[1,2,1,1,2,1,1,1,2,2]

[1,2,1,1,2,1]
```

I would like to use the second array to find the values in the first, but they must be in the same order.

Once for I would like it to return the next key up from the last key in the second array.

So in this example it would use the first six digits in the first array and then return 6 as the key after the final one in the second array.

Comment: Did you mean find [1,2,1,1,2,1] in [1,2,1,1,2,1,1,1,2,2] and all items in first array must be in same sequence and if found what will be the output?

Comment: Yes sorry, that is exactly what I mean :)
The output would then be the key above the final key in the sequence

Comment: Ok you mean result of [1,2,1,1,2,1,1,1,2,2] [1,2,1,1,2,1] will be 6 and [1,2,1,1,2,1,1,1,2,2] [1,2,1,1,3,1] will be 4?

Comment: When finding [1,2,1,1,2,1] in [1,2,1,1,2,1,1,1,2,2] it would return 6, I wouldn't do it the other way but yeah!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  var a2 =  [1,2,1,1,2,1,1,1,2,2]
var a1 = [1,2,1,1,0,1]
function find(arr1, arr2) {
    var len = 1
    var result = 0;
    var s2 = arr2.toString();
    for (len=1;len <= a1.length; len++)
    {
        var aa1 = arr1.slice(0, len)
        var s1 = aa1.toString();
        if(s2.indexOf(s1)>=0){
            result = aa1.length; 
        }
        else {
            break;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
alert(find(a1, a2));
```

Comment: What if the case is that the short array is [2,1,1,1,2,2] so it'll find the last lot of numbers and there is nothing to return?

Comment: rename a2 to a1 and a1 to a2 and try

Comment: This method would not be very fast (slice, join and indexOf in a loop).  Shef's method shows as more than 2x faster for small arrays in Chrome in this jsperf: http://jsperf.com/find-array-in-array.

Comment: I've tried tried renaming them and Firebug reports that a1 is not defined

Answer (score 0):

This is quick, this is dirty, and this is correct only if your data doesn't include any comma.

```
var needle =  [1,2,1,1,2,1];
var haystack = [1,2,1,1,2,1,1,1,2,2];


if ( needle.length <= 0 ) return 0;

var fromStr = ','+haystack.toString()+',' 
var findStr = ','+needle.toString()+','  

// Find ',1,2,1,1,2,1,' in ',1,2,1,1,2,1,1,1,2,2,'
var pos = fromStr.indexOf(findStr);
// Count the end position requested
return pos >= 0 ? fromStr.slice(0,pos+1).match(/,/g).length + needle.length - 1 : -1;
```

Note: The comma at head and tail is to make sure `[22,12]` doesn't match `[2,1]`.

Comment: Doesn't work if `needle` is empty.  (Also, the return-value for "not found" should be -1.)

Comment: Just curious, what should be returned if needle is empty? -1?

Comment: 0.  I am tempted to add "obviously", but by any definition of substring I can think of, it's 0.

Answer (score 0):

```
var find = function(haystack, needle) {
   var doesMatch = function(offset) {
       for (var i = 0; i < needle.length; i++) {
           if (haystack[i+offset] !== needle[i]) {
               return false;
           }
        }
        return true;
    };

    for (var j=0; j < haystack.length - needle.length; j++) {
         if (doesMatch(j)) {
            return j;
         }
    }
    return -1;
};
```